# How does internally elasticsearch use scroll_id

Tags: elasticsearch

How does internally elasticsearch use **scrollID** to return the result set in batches without changing its ID?

In my elasticsearch 6.2, I have more than 2 million records. I am querying it to fetch the records in a batch of 50. I am logging every scroll_id which is returned by ES6.2. But scroll ID id not changing.

So, just curious how ES knows that it has to send the next set of records.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll id is maintained on every shard.
Until there's a time out or you manually close the scroll, this scroll id remains.

Comment: Thanks, @dadoonet. But I want to know how es knows that it has to return the next batch of documents using the same scroll_id.

Comment: @amit.kewal because it keeps the last document returned with the scroll id on each shard. When a new request comes in with the same scroll id it just send from the last document.